# $\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(f(X))\cong \mathbb{F}_{p^d}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Let $f(X)$ be an irreducible polynomial of $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$, for some prime $p\in\mathbb{N}$. Assume that $\deg f(X)=d$. I  want prove that $$\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(f(X))\cong \mathbb{F}_{p^d}.$$
Any help?

Comment: Imo this question is heavily flawed and I am surprised about the answers. The only thing you can do here: 1. Show that the LHS is a field with $p^d$ elements. 2. Show that such a field is unique up to isomorphism 3. Thus call this field $\mathbb F_{p^d}$. Everything else does not make sense at all.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$F=\bigl(\mathbf F_pX]/(f(X))\bigr)^\times$ is a (multiplicative) group of order $p^d-1$. Use *Lagrange's theorem* and  uniqueness of the splitting field of a polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* What is the dimension of $K = \Bbb F_p[X]/(f(X))$ over its prime subfield?